# Does the independence of A with the union of B and C imply the independence of A with B and A with C?

Tags: probability

The question seems simple. But I just cannot figure it out properly: does it the following hold?

$A\perp B \cup C \Rightarrow A\perp B$ and $A \perp C$.

Here is a similar but different question:
[Does independence of B with individual events imply independence with the union of these events?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211682/does-independence-of-b-with-individual-events-imply-independence-with-the-union)

But I am not sure if the conclusion still holds in my case. Also, I do not quite understand the counterexamples there.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: take $B=A$ and $C=A^c$. $A$ will not be independent of itself unless $\mathbb{P}(A)=0$ or $1$, but $A$ is independent of $B\cup C=\Omega$.

Comment: Excellent counterexample! Thank you! @carmichael561

Answer (score 1):

A discrete example: Roll a fair die, and let $A=\{2,4,6\}$, $B=\{1\}$, $C=\{2\}$.

Comment: Thank you! @Henning Makholm