# Proving that increments are independent of the past for independent-increment stochastic processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose that a stochastic process $(X(t))_{0\le t<\infty}$ is of independent increments, i.e., $X(t_0), X(t_1)-X(t_0), \dots, X(t_n)-X(t_{n-1})$ are independent for any $0=t_0<\dots<t_n<\infty$ and $n$.

I want to prove the following result:

> $X(t)-X(s)$ is independent of
> $\mathcal{F}^X(s):=\sigma(X(u),0\le u\le s)$ for all $0\le s<t<\infty$.

To do so, let $\mathcal{D}$ be the collection of all sets in $\mathcal{F}^X(s)$ that is independent of $X(t)-X(s)$. **I want to show that $\mathcal{D}$ is a $\lambda$ set (Dynkin system).** The result follows then by the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem with the cylinder set as $\pi$-sytem in $\mathcal{D}$.

It is easy to show that $\Omega\in \mathcal{D}$, but I'm struggling with the other two properties. Take any $D,D'\in\mathcal{D}$ with $D\subset D'$. Let  $A:=(X(t)-X(s))^{-1}(B)$ for $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ Then, I need to show that

$$
\mathbb{P}((D'\setminus D)\cap A)=\mathbb{P}(D'\setminus D)\mathbb{P} (A)
$$

I can write $D'\setminus D=D'\cap D^c$, and I know that $D^c$ and  $A$ are independent, but I'm not sure how to proceed using the fact $\mathbb{P}(D\cap A)=\mathbb{P}(D)\mathbb{P}(A)$ and $\mathbb{P}(D'\cap A)=\mathbb{P}(D')\mathbb{P}(A)$.

Similarly, for the union property, I figure that it suffices to show for $D\cup D'$ by the continuity of the probability measure. I want to show that
$$
\mathbb{P}((D\cup D')\cap A)=\mathbb{P}(D\cup D')\mathbb{P}(A),
$$
and although this is intuitive, it looks like this is not true in general ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211682/does-independence-of-b-with-individual-events-imply-independence-with-the-union?rq=1)). Do I need to use something specific to the current setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the process is $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued (that is: $X_t:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$ for all $t\geq 0$). Define for $u>t$ fixed, $A\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$:
$$\mathscr{H}:=\{H\in \mathscr{F}_t:P(\{X_u-X_t\in A\}\cap H)=P(X_u-X_t\in A)P(H)\}$$
It is immediate that $\Omega\in \mathscr{H}$. Suppose $H \in \mathscr{H}$. Then:
$$\begin{aligned}P(X_u-X_t\in A)&=P(\{X_u-X_t\in A\}\cap H)+P(\{X_u-X_t\in A\}\cap H^c)\\
&=P(X_u-X_t\in A)P(H)+P(\{X_u-X_t\in A\}\cap H^c)\\
\implies P(X_u-X_t\in A)(1-P(H))&=P(\{X_u-X_t\in A\}\cap H^c)\\
\implies P(X_u-X_t\in A)P(H^c)&=P(\{X_u-X_t\in A\}\cap H^c)\end{aligned}$$
So $H^c \in \mathscr{H}$. Now let $(H_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathscr{H}$ pairwise disjoint. Then:
$$\begin{aligned}
P(\{X_u-X_t\in A\}\cap (\cup_nH_n))&=P(\cup_n(\{X_u-X_t\in A\}\cap H_n))\\
&=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}P(\{X_u-X_t\in A\}\cap H_n)\\
&=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}P(X_u-X_t\in A)P(H_n)\\
&=P(X_u-X_t\in A)\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}P(H_n)\\
&=P(X_u-X_t\in A)P(\cup_nH_n)
\end{aligned}$$
So $\mathscr{H}$ is a Dynkin $\lambda$-system. Now consider:
$$\begin{aligned}\mathscr{G}&:=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{t_0=0<t_1< t_2< ... < t_n\leq t}\sigma(X_{t_0},X_{t_1},X_{t_{2}},...,X_{t_n})\\
&=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{t_0=0<t_1< t_2< ... < t_n\leq t}\sigma(X_{t_0},X_{t_1}-X_{t_0},X_{t_{2}}-X_{t_{1}},...,X_{t_n}-X_{t_{n-1}})
\end{aligned}$$
We have $\sigma(\mathscr{G})=\mathscr{F}_t$ and $\mathscr{G}$ is $\cap$-stable and $\mathscr{G}\subseteq \mathscr{H}$ by the assumption of independent increments. By $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, and since $A$ was arbitrary, it follows that
$$P(\{X_u-X_t\in A\}\cap H)=P(X_u-X_t\in A)P(H),\forall H \in \mathscr{F}_t,\,\forall A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$$
which implies that $X_u-X_t$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_t$. Since $u>t$ were arbitrary, the claim follows.